# Trying to create a Math Input Panel in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-7, dllimport

How do I create a Math Input Panel in C#?

I have tried to put it into a dll and call it but it just closes right away.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include "micaut.h"
#include "micaut_i.c"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int run()
{
   CComPtr<IMathInputControl> g_spMIC; // Math Input Control
   HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
   hr = g_spMIC.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MathInputControl);
   hr = g_spMIC->EnableExtendedButtons(VARIANT_TRUE);
   hr = g_spMIC->Show();

   return hr;
}
```

I call the dll function in C# and the panel pops up but disappears right away. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your C# project, add a reference to the COM library `micautLib`. Then you can use the following code (in C#):

```
MathInputControl ctrl = new MathInputControlClass();
ctrl.EnableExtendedButtons(true);
ctrl.Show();
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly how you're supposed to do it, but this seems to work cleanly (complete program).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using micautLib;

namespace MathInputPanel
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            MathInputControl ctrl = new MathInputControlClass();
            ctrl.EnableExtendedButtons(true);
            ctrl.Show();
            ctrl.Close += () => Application.ExitThread();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the core issue, or how this code addresses it. The core issue is, that the thread instantiating the Math Input Control needs to run a message loop in order to dispatch its messages. This is an important detail.

Comment: @SamHarwell What is the location of COM Library micautLib? I tried the following in `VS2017` but it says `not found`: `Project-->Add Reference-->COM-->search  micautLib`. I probably need to browse to the relevant dll`. Please help