# Embedding the Math Input Panel in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use the **Math Input Panel** in a **WPF project**, but have no idea as to how I can make the panel to be apart of the WPF project (not a pop-up, or a lone window - it must be embedded in the project). I'm thinking of embedding it in a grid.

I got the panel to work in a windows form using the following example: [Math Input Panel with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623378/trying-to-create-a-math-input-panel-in-c-sharp) but then it comes up in a stand alone window, which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 with C#. If you need more information please feel free to ask.